# How is default avatar for new login created?

Tags: authentication

I have always noticed the default login avatar for stackoverflow is set to some
random graphics image. I was wondering how this avatar is created. Thank you.

Comment: I meant to put this post on stackexchange.

Comment: It seems to be a Gravatar Identicon.